# Memory leak using official resumable video upload for Youtube PHP API V3

Tags: memory-leaks, upload, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I try to upload large file in PHP to Youtube, using the API V3.
I just copied the official code [from there](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads).

It perfectly works for small uploads (<100Mo).
But when I try to upload large files, it returns :

```
    Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 102760448) (tried to allocate 1048577 
bytes) in /homepages/40/d216486693/htdocs/uploadsys.php on line 143
```

The code I use is just below, and line 143 is `$chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);`
My server can allow some more memory, but what if I try to upload **1**GB size files ?
In fact, the main problem is that if I check memory usage during the loop with chunk read & send, it never decrease !

It's just like if each chunk stays in memory... What can I do ? Tried to unset $chunk with no success

```
        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $filtre1 = array("&apos;","&#39;","'","\'");
        $snippet->setTitle(str_replace("\\","",str_replace($filtre1,"’",$title)));
        $snippet->setDescription("Descr");
        $snippet->setTags(explode(",",$keywords));
        $snippet->setCategoryId($ytcat);
        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->privacyStatus = "unlisted";

        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setStatus($status);
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        $client->setDefer(true);
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client,$insertRequest,'video/*',null,true,$chunkSizeBytes);
        $file_size = filesize($videofile);
        $media->setFileSize($file_size);

        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($videofile, "rb");
        $cc = 0;
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
          //Line 143 below
          $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
          $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
          $cc++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I removed the thanks in advance from your question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Mind to post your phpinfo()?

Comment: You will probably have more luck reporting this on https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues.

Comment: Why do you need to read the file into a variable? Try:
`$status = $media->nextChunk(fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've faced the same problem and solved it by reducing the chunk size.  The official code sample of `$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;` may cause the server to stop responding and report memory problems.  Reduce the size of the chunks and try again.

Comment: can you recommend a chunk size? we currently use 256kB and experience frequent timeouts. what are the downs of using low chunks?  I thought of using 64kB chunks. Is this too small for a average to slow  internet connection around 2-3 mbps?

Comment: Thanks for your reply; But it didn't work :S I had to upgrade PHP version